# Nested button in <a> tag with different onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a `button` that is nested in a tag `<a>`. Tag `<a>` has a `href` attribute and `button` calls a function. When I click on `button`, `button`'s function is called and then page is redirected to `href`. But I want to execute only the `button`'s function and not redirected when I click on `button`.

```
<a href='/path/to/somewhere' >
   <div >
     <someElements .... />
     <button onClick='someFunction();' >Click</button>
   </div>
</a>
```

You can suppose that `<a>` is a card and `href` is a path to details information. `button` can be a like or mark button in the card.

Comment: This is of course not valid HTML.

Comment: I didn't down vote. But those who did, did it because you didn't provide some code javascript of your attempt to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the event token to the onClick event and use `e.preventDefault()` to override the anchor tag event:

```js
function someFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('some function executed')
}
```

```html
<a href='/path/to/somewhere' >
   <div>
     <div>Element 1</div>
     <div>Element 2</div>
     <div>Element 3</div>
     <button onClick='someFunction(event);' >Click Me</button>
   </div>
</a>
```

It is probably better practices, though, to move the button outside of the anchor tag:

```js
function someFunction() {
  console.log('some function executed')
}
```

```html
<a href='/path/to/somewhere' >
   <div>
     <div>Element 1</div>
     <div>Element 2</div>
     <div>Element 3</div>
   </div>
</a>
<button onClick='someFunction();' >Click Me</button>
```

Comment: How did I forget that? I tried using `e.cancelBubble = true` and `e.stopPropagation()`. But I forgot `e.preventDefault()`!!!!!! Thanks @symlink

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion for moving the button outside of the anchor tag. But I need `button` inside the `<a>`.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a click event to the `a` element and check if the target of the event coming from the button execute `preventDefault()`

```js
document.querySelector('#link').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target === document.querySelector('#button')) {
    console.log('button clicked')
    event.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="link"><button id="button">button</button></a>
```

Comment: So where I can use this phrase? I used it in `button`'s function but not affected!

Comment: inside `someFunction` function

Comment: Not affected there!

Comment: The `button` has no target. It acts as a mark or like button. Or you can consider it writes a text in console.

Comment: @Morteza I just update the answer with code, please check again.

Comment: Thanks @Mina. Your Code works fine. But symlink's code is simpler than yours.

Comment: No problem, the important thing is that you got it, have a good day.